# Data annotation validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using service as an Model in view. I have connectionstring object in service. In View i bind it as

```
@Html.TextBox("IPAddress", Model != null ? Model.ConnectionString.Split(';')[0] : "", new { @id = "IPAddress", @class = "KCMSdropdownList" })

 @Html.TextBox("Port", Model != null ? Model.ConnectionString.Split(';')[1] : "", new { @id = "Port", @class = "KCMSdropdownList" })
```

I am validating model using DataAnnotation. For connecctionString i am not able to validate textbox. Can anyone help????
Thanks in Advance.

EDIT

So far I have tried this:

```
   [MetadataType(typeof(ConnectionStringMetadata))] 
   public partial class ConnectionString { public class ConnectionStringMetadata   {      
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter ConnectionString.")] 
   public int ConnectionString; } }
```

Then I try something

```
   [RegularExpression("/^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3});([0-9]‌​{1,5})$/",ErrorMessag="enter IPAddress"] 
   public string ConnectionString.Split(';')[0];
```

Comment: I try to add another metadata like
`
 [MetadataType(typeof(ConnectionStringMetadata))]
    public partial class ConnectionString
    {
        public class ConnectionStringMetadata
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter ConnectionString.")]
            public int ConnectionString;
        }
    }`
then I try something
[RegularExpression("/^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3});([0-9]{1,5})$/",ErrorMessag="enter IPAddress"]
public string ConnectionString.Split(';')[0];

Answer (score 0):

You should really be splitting up the connection string before you get to the view i.e. your model should be

```
public class ConnectionString{
    [RegularExpression("")]
    public string IPAddress {get; set;}
    public int Port {get; set;}
}
```

This will make it much easier to add validation